# R: Posix (Unix) Time Crazy Conversion

Tags: r, posix, posixct, posixlt

Unix time is 1435617000.

```
as.Date(1435617000,origin="01-01-1970")
[1] "3930586-11-23"
```

Which is wrong.  I'm trying to (a) get the correct date, which, per epoch converter is `GMT: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 22:30:00 GMT`.

How do I get R to tell me the month, day, year, hour, minute & second?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason why that happen is because `as.Date` converts arguments to class date objects. In this case you do not need a date but a class `POSIXct` object because your input, the `x` vector, contains other informations that `as.Date` is not able to manage. Another problem that even with the right function could appear, is that if when you do not specify the right time zone with the `tz` argument (except the case where your time zone is the same as the original time).

The following code does the job.

```
x <- 1435617000
as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01", tz ="GMT")
[1] "2015-06-29 22:30:00 GMT"
```

#### Use `as.Date`

Just in the case you wanted only the date but you have a complete Unix time like `x`, you have to just divide by `86400` (which is the number of seconds in a day!) to get only the right date.

```
 as.Date(x/86400L, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "2015-06-29"
```

#### Another important detail

The `origin` argument has to be supplied with `YYYY-MM-DD` and not like you did `DD-MM-YYYY` I am not sure but I think that the former is the only accepted and correct way.